# TypeScript avoid TS2749 and avoid using typeof on classes imported using require (run using bun)

Tags: typescript, import, require, bun

## The code

Given a file named foo.ts containing a class:

```
export default class Foo { name = 'bar' }
```

Given a program using this module:

```
const Foo = require('./foo').default
function logFoo(foo: Foo) { console.log(foo) }
logFoo(new Foo)
```

The program runs perfectly using bun:

```bash
bun test.ts
```

## The problem

It generates a TypeScript "**error TS2749: 'Foo' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof Foo'?**", on command line and into my WebStorm IDE.

Why that, and how to deal with it ?

Your answer should take care of these constraints:

- I know that replacing the `require` by `import Foo from './foo'` will remove the TS error: I just don't want to use import.
- I know declaring the parameter of the function like this: `foo: typeof Foo` will remove the TS error: I just don't want to use `typeof`, I want my function parameters to be declared the same way for a required class type, a local class type and an imported class type.

## Similar problem on a shorter example

I got the same problem with it, into a single program file:

```
class Foo { name = 'bar' }
const It = Foo
function logFoo(foo: It) { console.log(foo) }
logFoo(new Foo)
```

The parameter of type `It` throws a TS2749, but the parameter of type `Foo` is OK. Why and how to deal with it?

It is the same problem, without considerations about different module standards compatibility.

---

## Working cases

No TS2749 for these variants:

```
const Foo = require('./foo').default
function logFoo(foo: typeof Foo) { console.log(foo) }
logFoo(new Foo)
```

or:

```
import Foo from './foo'
function logFoo(foo: Foo) { console.log(foo) }
logFoo(new Foo)
```

But I want it to work with `require` and without `typeof`.

No TS2749 for these "bonus case" variants:

```
class Foo { name = 'bar' }
const It = Foo
function logFoo(foo: typeof It) { console.log(foo) }
logFoo(new Foo)
```

or:

```
class Foo { name = 'bar' }
const It = Foo
function logFoo(foo: Foo) { console.log(foo) }
logFoo(new Foo)
```

But I want it to work with `It` and without `typeof`.

Comment: Note that Bun does not do any typechecking when it runs TypeScript, it essentially just strips out all type info and executes the remaining JavaScript.